# What is the alternative IC to LAN9512 or LAN9514? this chip too HOT

Tags: usb, ethernet, temperature, usb-hub, compute-module

I am building a companion board with the Compute Module, USB & ethernet capability and running it 24/7 is part of the requirement. The standard practice would follow and use the same USB to Ethernet controller reference design from standard Pi Model A/B, LAN9512 or LAN9514 from Microchip.

As mentioned here [Raspberry pi too hot ? Let’s do something about it !](http://www.marc.ferradou.fr/Blog/2012/09/01/raspberry-pi-too-hot-lets-do-something-about-it/), I too find this chip is relatively VERY HOT (60'C)!

[image: LAN9512 60'C]

My operating environment involved running it 24/7 in a closed chassis where ventilation is usually bad. Fire hazard or chip burnt due to overheating is the last thing I want to see on my product.

My question is, is there any alternative ICs out there which dissipates much lower heat with the same functionality (USB host + Ethernet)? OR is there any 2 separate chip (USB host & Ethernet) which can archive the same end goal? I have no idea why Raspberry Pi Foundation chooses this chip in the first place, is so hot and bad for long-term operation

*Putting a small fan or bigger heatsink (I already had heatsink installed on top on both BCM2835 and LAN9512) is not the solution I am looking for, I like to seek a more energy efficient engineering solution

Comment: you gotta... chill out. It won't burn out. It's built to handle temps way hotter than that.

Comment: @PandaLion98 according the datasheet, it was design to up to 70'C (commercial version) & 85'C (industrial version), and I am living near the equator. Even after I put a heatsink, it still feels very hot when touching it

Comment: I am living **on** the equator. No overheating issues here. For the sense of touch, it is very "hot", but it is very normal for the chip.

Comment: I build board with LAN9514 for Compute Module, USB & Ethernet and running it 24/7.
The operation temperature is around 60 degree so that crushed computer modules raspberry pi V3.0 (I haven't got a problem on raspberry pi V1.1 ). Is there any alternative to replace LAN9514 or solution for raspberry pi V3.0?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use ASIX chips, such as AX88178 / AX88772B